# Understanding /etc/aliases

Tags: linux, email, unix, sendmail

I know that /etc/aliases is used to provide mail alias for system users (for either Sendmail or Postfix), for example, the listing like those in [Understanding /etc/aliases and what it does](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65013/understanding-etc-aliases-and-what-it-does).

However, can I use names beside system users? I.e., if I want to use an alias `softball`, do I need to create that `softball` user account first?

I've gone through the following docs, but still am not sure about it.

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65013/understanding-etc-aliases-and-what-it-does
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7612/mail-45/index.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4555/mailrefer-35/index.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36828/mailadmin-106.html
- http://bsdwiki.reedmedia.net/wiki/Create_or_modify_email_aliases_for_Sendmail_or_Postfix.html
- https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_53/com.ibm.aix.files/doc/aixfiles/aliases.htm
- https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/sendmail.html

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alias source can be anything. That's pretty much the point of aliases – many systems will have entries like `postmaster: root` without a matching OS account.